# Java Method has the functionality of an IF-THEN-ELSE statement

Tags: java

Is there any method has the functionality of an IF-THEN-ELSE statement in java like `decode` function in Oracle/PLSQL ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking/needing. What's wrong with a simple `if { ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: @BalusC please look at this. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php. isn't this simple than `if { ... } else { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, but you are asking for something like this:

```
interface CaseItem<K, V> {
    boolean isDefaultCondition();

    @NotNull
    K conditionValue();

    V calculateResult();
}
```

---

```
public <T, V> V decode(@NotNull T input, CaseItem<K, V> caseItems...) {
    if (caseItem == null) {
        return null;
    }

    for (CaseItem<K, V> caseItem : caseItems) {
        if (input.equals(caseItem.conditionValue()) {
            return caseItem.calculateResult();
        } else if (caseItem.isDefaultCondition()) {
            return caseItem.calculateResult();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: In this solution at most one single value is calculated in the case of need.

Answer (score 2):

I hope not such method is there in JAVA, you can use `if-then-else` or simply switch blocks if your case is only `byte/short/char/int`.

Comment: Or `enum`, since Java 5, or even `String`, since Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

From [the link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) which you supplied in the question comment:

> You could use the decode function in an SQL statement as follows:
>
> ```
> SELECT supplier_name,
> decode(supplier_id, 10000, 'IBM',
>                     10001, 'Microsoft',
>                     10002, 'Hewlett Packard',
>                            'Gateway') result
> FROM suppliers;
> ```

The closest would be the conditional operator:

```
String supplierName = supplierId == 10000 ? "IBM"
                    : supplierId == 10001 ? "Microsoft"
                    : supplierId == 10002 ? "Hewlett Packard"
                    : "Gateway";
```

Or maybe a (static) dictionary/map:

```
Map<Integer, String> suppliers = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
suppliers.put(10000, "IBM");
suppliers.put(10001, "Microsoft");
suppliers.put(10002, "Hewlett Packard");
suppliers.put(null, "Gateway");
// ...

String supplierName = suppliers.get(supplierId);
if (supplierName == null) supplierName = suppliers.get(null);
```

Comment: The good thing about decode is each value is calculated only if needed. But in your solution values must be calculated before.

Answer (score 0):

isn't

expression? dothis: elseDothis something similar.

i==0 ? true : false is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a map like collection that only creates it's values on request, but caches previously requested values, take a look at the Google Guava [Cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) and [LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html).

Otherwise go for the `switch` or other language based conditional statements as it will make you code far more readable and maintainable.